# Asking to enter paraphrase,while creating a release for android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, jarsigner

So,i;m trying to create a release of android app on ionic framework,i already have did all the procedure before,so i have a keystore file with me,now i'm trying to sign the apk with that specific keystore file,which is asking for paraphrase,which i assume is the password,but when i enter it it says "the system cannot find the file specified"

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   simple.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk key0
>
> Enter Passphrase for keystore:
>
> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\simple.keystore (The system cannot find
>   the file specified)

The apk and keystore file are there in the root directory

Answer (score 1):

So,it turns out,you cannot put your keystore file and apk in Java>jdk>bin,even if you have given administrative access to the command prompt,moving the files did the trick